# web3.py createFilter: filter => SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: events, web3.py, filters

- Web3.py version 4.2.1
- geth version: `1.8.0-unstable`

---

I have followed [web3.py guide](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html?highlight=eventFilter#module-web3.utils.filters) for filtering.

> Through the contract instance api:
>
> ```
> event_filter = mycontract.events.myEvent.createFilter(fromBlock='latest', {'filter':{'arg1':10}})
> ```

---

But I get an error for this line:

```
myContract.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock='latest', {'filter': {'arg1':10}})
```

My main goal is the filter events based on their arguments.

Error I am having:

```
myContract.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock='latest', {'filter': {'arg1':10}})
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

**[Q]** How could I fix this error?

---

**Update:** I have followed @Mikko Ohtamaa 's answer. Now I do not get any error, but filter returns `[]` even I provide correct event's keyword (dictionary of argument name and its value).

*Please see an example:*

```
blockReadFrom = 1899201;
myFilter = eBlocBroker.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock=blockReadFrom)
print(myFilter.get_all_entries())
```

Returns, here you can see that there is emitted event with `'storageID': 0` under `AttributeDict`:

```
[AttributeDict({'address': '0x128c9F368F12C24Cc2a4f88dCDCf3daA13C9667e', 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x8f7c50fe276057ea90985be6d14dc7abb79ee0430c66bd161861b582b7db0c97'), 'args': AttributeDict({'desc': 'Science', 'jobKey': 'QmRsaBEGcqxQcJbBxCi1LN9iz5bDAGDWR6Hx7ZvWqgqmdR', 'index': 21, 'storageID': 0, 'clusterAddress': '0x75A4c787c5c18C587B284a904165Ff06a269B48C'}), 'transactionIndex': 0, 'event': 'LogJob', 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x9782cb281aa72defe54e0f84055a03a0b1bf6c6f21bd3d276a1252098f83c15f'), 'logIndex': 0, 'blockNumber': 1899201})]
```

---

```
blockReadFrom = 1899201;
myFilter = eBlocBroker.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock=blockReadFrom, argument_filters={'storageID':0})
print(myFilter.get_all_entries())
```

Returns:

```
[]
```

---

And interesting point that following line returns a valid output even though {`'arg1': 999` or  `'arg111': 999` etc.} does not exists.

`myFilter = eBlocBroker.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock=blockReadFrom, argument_filters={'arg1': 999})`

---

**Note:**

For more information please follow this closed issue: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/943#event-1723643072

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
  myContract.events.LogJob.createFilter(fromBlock='latest', argument_filters={'arg1':10})
```

You can see the actual function signature here:

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html?highlight=createfilter

Please file an issue regarding web3.py documentation page as it does not reflect the current codebase.

Comment: Should `arg1` be the keyword that is defined under the event ? Now it does not give any error, but it returns `[]` even I provide correct event's keyword (dictionary of argument name and its value). Please see my updated answer  @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: For more information please follow this closed issue: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py/issues/943#event-1723643072