# How to filter indexed events and watch callback return value using Web3.py

Tags: events, web3.py

*For example*, I have an `event` where using `clusterAddress` as key, I want to find the other arguments (`storageID`, `desc`, etc.), only having the `clusterAddress` indexed.

I added the `indexed` keyword for the `clusterAddress` argument.

```
event LogJob(address indexed clusterAddress,
             string jobKey,
             uint index,
             uint8 storageID,        
             string desc
     );
```

---

Later, should the following approach work under `Web3.py` (following this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/52545/4575)) or should I do something else to capture the `indexed` argument variable using `Web3.py`?

```
   def print_message(received_message): #{
      print(received_message)
      received_messages.append(received_message)
   #}

   blockReadFrom = 1899690;
   myFilter = eBlocBroker.events.LogJob.createFilter(
       fromBlock=blockReadFrom,
       argument_filters={'clusterAddress': '0x4e4a0750350796164D8DefC442a712B7557BF282'}
   )
   print(myFilter.get_all_entries())

  received_messages = []
  myFilter.watch(print_message) # Error occurs: AttributeError: 'LogFilter' object has no attribute 'watch'
```

---

Overall, I want to filter all the events using `web3.py` by passing the indexed argument. When I try to `watch` the `LogFilter` ([like Watch callback return value `Web3.js`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#watch-callback-return-value)); I have receive following error: `AttributeError: 'LogFilter' object has no attribute 'watch'`

**=>** How to get all the events with the passed argument? After that if possible how could I `watch` the upcoming new emitted events?

Comment: can you share what problem are you facing with this snippet?

Comment: I just wanted to double check my approach is correct. Please also see my updated question: I am not able to `watch` the filter I have created. @HarshVakharia

Comment: I have updated my answer!

Comment: Is there any alternative for watch() function? @Harsh Vakharia

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Regarding the `watch` method, it has been removed from v4. So except last 2 lines, your code should just work for v4.

From the snippet of your smart contract, you can filter events using `clusterAddress` just like you have in your code snippet.

Make sure you are setting right `fromBlock` and the event you are filtering for should occur after that block.

Comment: Thanks! So there’s no way with web3.py to listen to events other than setting up a loop with a fixed polling interval?